# What is the Tomcat/temp directory in Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

A fresh download of Tomcat 7 (I'm using 7.0.19) contains a 'temp' directory containing the single file, 'safeToDelete.tmp'. What is this directory used for by Tomcat or how is should be used by Tomcat users (developers)?

Answer (score 28):

When you startup Tomcat, using `startup.bat` (Windows) or `startup.sh`, it calls `catalina.bat`/`catalina.sh` respectively.

Catalina then needs a temp directory to be set. It does this by setting the `CATALINA_TMPDIR` variable to `TOMCAT_HOME\temp` folder and assigns it to java system environment variable as `java.io.tmpdir`.

This is copied from `catalina.bat`:

```
rem   CATALINA_TMPDIR (Optional) Directory path location of temporary directory
rem                   the JVM should use (java.io.tmpdir).  Defaults to
rem                   %CATALINA_BASE%\temp.
```

Where `CATALINA_BASE` is `TOMCAT_HOME` (if run using the `startup` script).

We carry on:

```
if not "%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" == "" goto gotTmpdir
set "CATALINA_TMPDIR=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp"
```

Finally:

```
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
:doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
goto end
```

Finally, the `java.io.tmpdir` is pointed to the `CATALINA_TMPDIR` where the JVM write temporary files including disk-based storage policies.

Comment: The OP asked what the `tmp` folder is used for.

Comment: @Reimius, I added further notes for clarification.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a Ubuntu thing, but it's worth noting that many of the relevant settings are defined in `/etc/default/tomcat7`