# Location to write application specific files

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, file-upload, groovy

The extracted war will show the following folder structure:

- assets
- META-INF
- WEB-INF

Where should the application be configured to write files? Is there a mechanism already available for this?

Note: middle-tier administrator with custom deployment pipeline in place asking

**Edit**
The files stored need to be also served by the application.

Comment: What do you want to archive? What files do you need to write?

Comment: The app seems to accept incoming files that are processed and spit back out to the client. Then, they are deleted. I am the one setting this path, due to our custom deployment pipeline. I'm not sure if I should set a folder at the root of the site or under another path entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration depends on server. For Tomcat, it's configured using `$CATALINA_TMPDIR` parameter, which is optional. For more info, please refer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/13523/configure-tomcat-to-use-a-different-temp-directory-for-file-uploads) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112591/what-is-the-tomcat-temp-directory-in-tomcat-7).